# How to use multiple classes to hide all elements but one using css only

Tags: html, css, image, hide, display

Is it possible to use multiple classes on html  elements to display only one and hide the others with css ?

In practice I have a wp website that must display a different logo depending on locale (fr/en), screen sizes and dpi.

Here's my html

```
<div id='site-logo' class='logo'>
<img class='logo-fr logo-desktop logo-hidpi' src='http://path/logo_fr-2x.png'>
<img class='logo-fr logo-mobile logo-hidpi' src='http://path/logo_fr_mobile-2x.png'>
<img class='logo-en logo-desktop logo-hidpi' src='http://path/logo_en-2x.png'>
<img class='logo-en logo-mobile logo-hidpi' src='http://path/logo_en_mobile-2x.png'>
<img class='logo-fr logo-desktop logo-lodpi' src='http://path/logo_fr.png'>
<img class='logo-fr logo-mobile logo-lodpi' src='http://path/logo_fr_mobile.png'>
<img class='logo-en logo-desktop logo-lodpi' src='http://path/logo_en.png'>
<img class='logo-en logo-mobile logo-dpi' src='http://path/logo_en_mobile.png'>
```

and here's the relevant css :

```
/*Scalable logos*/
#site-logo {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 331px;
  max-height: 235px;
  margin-top: 20% !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
}

#site-logo img{
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*Logo FR*/
:lang(fr) > .logo-en img{
  display: none;
}

/*Logo EN*/
:lang(en) > .logo-fr img{
  display: none;
}

/* Hide lo-dpi logos for Hi-dpi screens*/
@media  only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
only screen and (min-resolution: 120dpi){
  .logo-lodpi img{
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Hide hi-dpi logos for Lo-dpi screens*/
@media  only screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
only screen and (-o-max-device-pixel-ratio: 13/10),
only screen and (max-resolution: 120dpi){
  .logo-hidpi img{
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Hide desktop logos for small screens (mobile etc...)*/
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .logo-desktop img{
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Hide mobile logos for large screens (desktop)*/
@media (min-width:769px) {
  .logo-mobile img{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

...which displays no logo on webkit browsers and 8 on firefox.

I'd prefer a pure css solution for this as I'm learning css on the go for this very project (I resorted to "intersecting" classes after I tried  changing the img's `content` with css (but that works for webkit and not firefox) and using `background` for a `site-logo::after` pseudo-element (but it doesn't flex).

If you think of a simpler solution I'll definitely use it but I'm curious if something like that could be done...

Comment: not sure what you are asking here. In what situation did the logo still shows and it should be hidden?

Comment: It showed all eight versions of the logo in firefox instead of just one. But I got it to work by removing the `img` after my class selectors in the css. Thanks for your willingness to help @YongQuan !